# Ninject Clearing Out Resolved Instances

Tags: ninject

I have some bindings that are setup as singletons. I want them to always return the same instance until a certain point at which I want all the singleton instances to be cleared. I don't want to remove and re-add the bindings, just clear out the instances that have been created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singletons are only single per kernel.  You could just create a new kernel.

Alternatively, it seems that you don't really want singletons.  How about using a class that contains the references you need.

Comment: Currently I am just creating a new kernel. I do want a singleton because I want everywhere the type is injected to be the same object. there is a point when I want it cleared though.

What I'm doing is setting up NHibernate with WCF and I want an ISession PerCall. I could reuse the kernel because the config doesn't change at all, but on every call I want the instances to be reset. So for now I'm creating a new kernel on every call, but I could just keep the kernel around if there was a way to clear out the instances.